# Json Dropdown Postback Response

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My Ajax calls:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "HazzardsDashBoards.aspx/GetReport",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',

        complete: function (jqXHR)
        {
           var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
           TrendChart(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
           alert("error");
        }
    });

    $(".ddlChange").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "HazzardsDashBoards.aspx/GetReport1",
            data:  JSON.stringify({ company: $("#ddl_PermitCmpny").val(), dept: $("#ddl_Agency").val() }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function (jqXHR)
            {
                var data = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                TrendChart(data);
            },
            error :function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
                alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jqXHR + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Server Methods:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetReport()
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    try
    {

            string strQry = string.Empty;

            strQry = " select YEAR(dt_ModifiedOn)[date],COUNT(*) [HazardCount] from tbl";
            strQry += " where int_PluginID = 4 and int_FeatureID=35  ";
            strQry += " group by year(dt_ModifiedOn) ";

            using (commonManager)
            {
                DataTable dt = commonManager.ExecuteDataTable(strQry);

                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
    return rows;
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetReport1(string company, string dept)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    try
    {
        string strQry = string.Empty;

        strQry = " select YEAR(mwl.dt_ModifiedOn)[date],COUNT(*) [HazardCount] from tbl";
        strQry += " left outer join tbl1 thzd on thzd.int_HAZARD_ID = mwl.str_ObjectID";
        strQry += " where int_PluginID = 4 and int_FeatureID=35 ";
        if (company != "")
        {
            if (company == "1")
            {
                strQry += " and  str_ReportFromType = 'E'";
            }
            else
            {
                strQry += " and  str_ReportFromType = 'C'";
            }
        }

        if (dept != null && dept != string.Empty)
        {
            if (company == "1")
            {
                strQry += " and thzd.str_72_ME = '" + dept + "' ";
            }
            if (company == "2")
            {
                strQry += " and thzd.smallint_5865_ME = '" + dept + "' ";
            }

        }


        strQry += " group by year(mwl.dt_ModifiedOn) ";

        using (commonManager)
        {
            DataTable dt = commonManager.ExecuteDataTable(strQry);

            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
    return rows;
}
```

I am getting same json response for both ajax calls, after dropdown selection also I am getting same json response.
Data is overriden after dropdown selection and data is not being reflected.

Ajax call is firing and going to respective method but the data is not being reflected and showing same data.
I need to get the different json responses for different ajax calls as when dropdown changes and page load.

Comment: What is TrendChart?

Comment: If you are getting same `json` response, then you need to show your serverside method..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I added reedited and added server methods please check

Comment: You are passing some date in your 2nd `ajax` request but you aren't receiving it at server method..

Comment: I am getting json response after some time it's been replacing by first ajax method response.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your first AJAX call will run **every single time the page loads**.I'm suspecting that after you call `GetReport1()` a post back happens and the jQuery load event runs which will override your `TrendChart()` logic by calling `GetReport()`.

You can place an `alert('Page Loading...');` statement just after `$(document).ready(function(){` to test this theory.

You could be using an ASP.NET `DropDownList` control which causes the post back, if that's the case try replacing it with a simple HTML `<select>` and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: @Dennis I am binding data from database todropdown so i cant replace asp.net dropdown list with html select

Comment: Does your drop down list have AutoPostBack="true"?You need to identify what is causing the postback in your code

Comment: what you said is exactly  correct about the ajax call is correct,Page loading is called two times, so how to get rid of these issue.

Comment: Like I said, you need to identify what is causing the PostBack in your page and remove\replace this logic.

Comment: yes for my dropdown i need that attribute autopostback because when dropdown changes i need to get modified data.

Comment: I have an update panel does it causes the postback every time?

Comment: Well that's your problem.Why do you need AutoPostBack="true"?You get the data using $ajax call in jQuery.Remove it and your code will work.Update panel just gives you an "illusion" that there is no PostBack.The PostBack still happens

Comment: if i remove autopost back its working but charts are coming one by one instead of update.